# Windows 7 Ultimate, Office 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel

while working in Excel - Office 2010, i observed that "Insert" tab next to "Home" Tab is missing.
Appreciate help as to how to get it back.I tried Excel Options, Customize and tried to add the "insert"Tab but did not work.

Comment: You could try repairing office through "Programs and features" in "Control Panel".

Answer (score 0):

Reset the ribbon, as instructed [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-the-ribbon-3c610b47-6f0f-4179-83d3-68a254a80ea6). Summary:

- Right click on a ribbon tab
- Select "Customize the ribbon..."
- Click "Reset all customizations"